# Sort Function didn't work properly inside a loop

Tags: c, sorting

I am trying to "re-sort" every time the array (cities) that updated with a new one value and display the current state of table.

When i am putting function sort inside the for-loop, the sort doesn't work properly and just replace the values. For example, firstly if i give "aba" it prints "aba" , secondly if i give "bad" it prints " aba , bad " , thirdly if i give "dad" it prints "aba,dad". The sort replaces with the last value. **The paradox is that outside the for loop it works properly.** Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
void sort(char** cities) 
{ 
    int i, j; 

    // Perform sort operation using bubble sort 
    for (i = 0; i < 3 - 1; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < 3 - i - 1; j++) 
            if (strcmp(cities[j], cities[j + 1]) > 0) { 
                char* temp; 
                temp = (char*)calloc(30, sizeof(char)); 
                strcpy(temp, cities[j]); 
                strcpy(cities[j], cities[j + 1]); 
                strcpy(cities[j + 1], temp); 
            } 
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char** cities;

    cities = (char**)calloc(3,sizeof(char*)); 

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
         cities[i]=(char*)calloc(3,sizeof(char));
    }

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("Give City %d:\n",i); 
        scanf("%s",cities[i]);
        if (i==0)
            printf("%s\n",cities[0]); //1st case of nothing to compare
        else
        {
            sort(cities);
            printf("\nArray after sorting %d time:\n",i); 
            for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) 
                printf("%s\n", cities[i]);    //prin current array of cites sorted
        }
    }

    free(cities);            
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: The fact that the sort function always sorts three elements even as you increase the number of elements from 1 to 3 is worrying.

Comment: Your sort function seems to assume that there are always exactly three elements in the array.

Comment: i have a standard number of cities @JohnBollinger

Comment: the problem is `cities[i]=(char*)calloc(3,sizeof(char));` , look my answer

Comment: @laland, you sort as if there were 3 cities even when there are only *two* cities.

Comment: @bruno i have changed and still replace...

Comment: an other the problem is the fact you apply _strcmp_ on a non initialized string, look my answer, I edited it

Comment: Outside the loop why sort works corectly? @bruno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>  cities[i]=(char*)calloc(3,sizeof(char));
> ```

a city name can only have 2 characters more the null ending character, after the behavior is undefined, probably you wanted a longer name

but in

> ```
> scanf("%s",cities[i]);
> ```

probably you enter more that 2 characters ...

---

You call *sort* without indicating how much cites was enter, so *sort* works on 3 cities even only 2 was enter, and access to the third string before it is initialized, with an undefined behavior when *strcmp* accesses it

---

In

> ```
> temp = (char*)calloc(30, sizeof(char));
> ```

you create a memory leak because you do not freed *temp*,

there is no reason to allocate in the heap to exchange : exchange the pointers not the contents

You also do not free the name of the cities at the end of main

---

A proposal from your code, managing any number of cities, the input ends on EOF (control-d), the name of the city are limited to 30 chars (look at the protection in *scanf*)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort(char** cities, int n) 
{ 
    int i, j; 

    // Perform sort operation using bubble sort 
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
        if (strcmp(cities[j], cities[j + 1]) > 0) { 
          char* temp = cities[j]; 

          cities[j] =  cities[j + 1];
          cities[j + 1] = temp;
        }
      } 
    }
} 

int main() {
  char ** cities = malloc(0);
  char name[31];
  int n = 0, i;

  while (printf("Give City %d:\n", n), (scanf("%30s", name) == 1))
  {
    cities = realloc(cities, (++n) * sizeof(char *));
    cities[n - 1] = strdup(name);

    if (n == 1)
      printf("%s\n",cities[0]); //1st case of nothing to compare
    else {
      sort(cities, n);
      printf("\nArray after sorting %d time:\n", n); 
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        printf("%s\n", cities[i]);    //print current array of cites sorted
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    free(cities[i]);

  free(cities);            

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Give City 0:
qsd
qsd
Give City 1:
aze

Array after sorting 2 time:
aze
qsd
Give City 2:
wxc

Array after sorting 3 time:
aze
qsd
wxc
Give City 3:
<control-d>
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==23191== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23191== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23191== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23191== Command: ./a.out
==23191== 
Give City 0:
qsdqsdqsd
qsdqsdqsd
Give City 1:
aze

Array after sorting 2 time:
aze
qsdqsdqsd
Give City 2:
wxcwxcwxcwxcwxc

Array after sorting 3 time:
aze
qsdqsdqsd
wxcwxcwxcwxcwxc
Give City 3:
<control-d>
==23191== 
==23191== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23191==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23191==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 2,102 bytes allocated
==23191== 
==23191== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==23191== 
==23191== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23191== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Comment: so you suggest just ```char temp```?

Comment: @laland I encourage you to study each line of that solution with attention ;-)

Comment: because i am new in this, can you explain me more this while syntax (i mean more analytical)

Comment: @laland a form `expr_1, expr2_, .... expr_n` (out of a function call, I don't speak about parameters ;-) ) executes all the `expr_i` in order and value the result of `expr_n` (the last). So the _while_ test expression executes the _printf_ then the _scanf_ and value the _scanf_ result. This is not very usual but practical to do

Comment: and if i want to finish the while in specific number how can i modify this?

Comment: if the number of loops is limited you can do a _for_, or add a `&& (n != maxnumber)` or something like that

Comment: Ok got it, Thank you!

Comment: @laland BTW the condition is probably the first, so  `while((n != max) && (printf(...), scanf(...) == 1)) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

Although @bruno is right that you are allocating insufficient memory for your city names, solving that will probably not resolve the issue because you have a deeper, *algorithmic* problem.

Your sort function itself looks correct(-ish) for sorting an array of exactly three elements.  It does leak memory, and it would be better to just swap around the pointers than to copy the string contents, but it should successfully put the elements in increasing lexicographic order.  But as I observed in comments, however, you call it not only after having read all the city data, but also after having read only the first two.  Consider what will happen then.

Answer: since you are allocating the string data via `calloc()`, the contents are initialized to all-zero.  In particular, then, initially the byte at index zero in each string is 0, so that the string will be interpreted as an empty string.  ***When you sort after having populated only two array elements, the empty string at the third position will sort to the beginning of the array.***  When you then read the third city name, you overwrite whichever string had sorted to the third position.  Then when you print the cities at the end, you overlook the fact that there is an extra blank line at the beginning of the city list, where the empty string you sorted to the front was printed.

Best would be to wait to sort until all the data have been input.  Given that you're reading all the data at once, there is little advantage to sorting at intermediate stages.  But if you must sort after having input only some of the elements, then you must be sure to sort only the elements that have been read up to that point.

Comment: I see your point and maybe you are right but i need to resort every time that a value  insert in the array , In this case what can i do? (PS: indeed there is a blank line)

Comment: @laland, I already answered that in my third paragraph.  To put it another way, though, when you sort after reading only two cities, you must sort as if the array is only two elements long.  That will require you to modify your sort function so that it accommodates arrays of different lengths, as specified by an additional parameter, a global variable (ugh), or some other means.

Comment: How is possible with extra parameter in function? sth like this ```sort(n,char** cities)``` but again n will be const

Comment: Yes, @laland, something a bit like that.  You'll want to specify a type for parameter `n`, however.